# How to enhance build with a sbt plugin dynamically, i.e. without saving it?

Tags: sbt

I often want to add `sbt-dependency-graph-sugar` to the current session. The way I do it currently is:

```
> reload plugins
> set addSbtPlugin("com.gilt" % "sbt-dependency-graph-sugar" % "0.7.4")
> session save
> reload return
> dependencyTree
```

And then reverting the change on the filesystem later. Is there a way to do this in less steps and without changing the build files?

Comment: Not yet, but I believe there's an open ticket for this.

Comment: I see. Thanks, Josh. And if you find that ticket, I'd love to subscribe to it (tried a few things, no luck)

Comment: Ok, the ticket was only in our internal sprint planner, so I added it publicly: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per comments from @jsuereth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137042/how-do-i-add-a-sbt-plugin-in-to-an-sbt-session-ie-without-saving#comment39174781_25137042):

The feature is not possible yet in sbt and there is the ticket [Add plugins via a command](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1502) to track it.